User session is not taking any inputs after 15 mins of login
I am a root user in a ubuntu server (22.04), I switched to another user ,after 15 minutes the terminal is not showing any input I give, not executing any thing , only enter works if I press enter it is going to new line and unable to logout of the user session. For new session we need to close putty and need to login again. Any troubleshooting for this issue
Thanks.

Try check the users .bashrc or .bash_profile files if there is anything blocking. sudo less ~user/.bashrc (replace user with the affected username)

I have tried for what you have mentioned but issue still persists
